# HTML <option> tag does not display label/name value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
    for(let i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('elemsList').innerHTML += ('<option value="'+ this.elems[i].id +' label="' +this.elems[i].name +'"></option>');
}
```

(it tried lable="" and name="")
produces the list for a texfield to filter through. This list displays the id value large and the label value smaller beneath it. when choosing an option the field is filled with the id value.

How do i have to change it to only display the name value both in the list and in the field, but when submitting the form it belongs to access the id value?

```
    for(let i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('elemsList').innerHTML += ('<option value="'+ this.elems[i].id +'>' +this.elems[i].name +'</option>');
}
```

has the same result. 
I am using Angular, and the list is a `<data-list>`

Edit: [This is what the list looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P37MT.png) I want it to just display the name. But when the form is submitted it should use the id value.

In JS i load the list like this

```
  loadElemList() {
for(let i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('elemsList').innerHTML += ('<option value='+ this.elems[i].id +'>' +this.elems[i].name +'</option>');
}
  }
```

The HTML

```
  <tr><td><label>Elem:</label></td><td>
<input #elem list="elemList" name="elem" />
<datalist id="elems">
</datalist></td></tr>
```

And the form gets the value from the list with

```
elem.value
```

Where elem.value should be the id but the user only sees the name.

Comment: It's not clear what the final form of the HTML (or the beginning for that matter). Please show a [mre] of the behavior. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: I think you have not incorporated inverted commas around the string.It should be as 
document.getElementById('elemsList').innerHTML += ('<option value='+ this.elems[i].id +'>' +this.elems[i].name +'</option>');

Comment: `<option value="id label="name"></option>` <-- look at what it would render....

Comment: unclear why you would be adding option elements like this in angular.

Comment: I edited the post to clarify what i meant. Also I tried everything you suggested but it stayed the same non the less. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: i also tried using 'ngFor but that just makes everything disapear that why i am using that loop in JS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were missing " after the value. Try the following:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.elems.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('elemsList').innerHTML += ('<option value="' + this.elems[i].id +'" label="' + this.elems[i].name + '"></option>');
}
```

This might produce what you want, apologies if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thanks i fixed that but that sadly was not the problem